# jvm monitoring - from command line

Tags: java, linux, jvm, monitoring

I am looking for commands to run in a Linux VM, to continuously monitoring the following metrics for my client:

```
jvm.cpu_load.process
jvm.thread_count
jvm.non_heap_memory
jvm.heap_memory_max
```

Could you help me to find the exact command to get these metrics?

Comment: Maybe use jmx or jcmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some this information by running `jcmd` repeatedly against your process. Run `jcmd <pid> help` to find out what your JVM supports. For example, you can get information about the process' use of memory by running `jcmd <pid> GC.heap_info`.

However, if you want to get this information regularly, you should look at writing a program to query either JMX (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html) or by using JFR to gain this data. If you're Java 14 o above, then you can use JFR Streaming to process the data as it comes off (added in [JEP 394](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/349)).

JFR is an always-on profiling mechanism which periodically dumps data that you can process, but in non-streaming mode, it will dump contents after a particular amount of data is collected.

If you're looking to just monitor metrics remotely, writing a JMX tool is probably the recommended way of doing it, or using an existing tool like NewRelic's agent or [Netflix's Servo](https://github.com/Netflix/servo) library to acquire this data via JMX if you don't want to write it yourself.